# Graphql/bcrypt error "Illegal arguments: string, function"

Tags: graphql, bcrypt

I am working with graphql to signup/sign in. Registration runs smoothly but I am running into this the bcrypt error upon logging back in. When I change it to user.password in the if statement below the loginUser function, it says throws a newUser is undefined error. Where is my error in this one?

Resolvers:

```
const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    async registerUser(_, { registerInput: { username, email, password } }) {
  
 const previousUser = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (previousUser) {
        throw new ApolloError(
          "A user with this email already exists" + email,
          "User_Already_Exists"
        );
      }

      var encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

      const newUser = new User({
        username: username,
        email: email.toLowerCase(),
        password: encryptedPassword,
      });

      const token = jwt.sign(
        { user_id: newUser._id, email },
        "this is the secret",
        {
          expiresIn: "2h",
        }
      );

      newUser.token = token;
  
      const res = await newUser.save();
      return {
        id: res.id,
        ...res._doc,
      };
    },
    async loginUser(_, { loginInput: { email, password } }) {
 
      const user = await User.findOne({ email });

      if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.model))) {
 
        const token = jwt.sign(
          { user_id: newUser._id, email },
          "this is the secret",
          {
            expiresIn: "2h",
          }
        );
 
        user.token = token;
  
        return {
          id: res.id,
          ...res._doc,
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to compare to `user.password` not `user.model`
2. `newUser` isn't defined if the passwords match, use `user` instead.

```
async loginUser(_, { loginInput: { email, password } }) {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
    const token = jwt.sign(
      { user_id: user._id, email },
      "this is the secret",
      { expiresIn: "2h"}
    );
    user.token = token; // this isn't used anywhere, why?
    return {id: res.id,...res._doc}; // this looks wrong too, res is not in scope
  }
}
```

Comment: This did work Michael! I thought I had replied but see not that i did not. Thanks so much!

Comment: Cool! Feel free to accept the answer! 